# Cannot npm run dev. cross-env: not found . I have put path. however it says not find

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, amazon-linux

My project is not able to do  `npm run dev`.
cross-env: not found .error happened.
I changed my package.json.
below

```
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js  NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
```

I have put path. However it still says "not found".

```
$ sudo npm run dev
```

```
@ dev /var/www/bb
npm run development


> @ development /var/www/bb
> node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

module.js:478
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/var/www/bb/node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:476:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:611:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:160:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:507:3

npm ERR! Linux 4.14.231-173.361.amzn2.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "development"
npm ERR! node v6.17.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! @ development: `node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
```

```
$ npm install webpack
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use cross-env or any other module, please make sure it's there in package.json and you have run yarn install or npm install in that directory containing the package.json. If the problem still persists, try deleting the node_modules folder in this directory and try running yarn install or npm install again.